# How to protect flutter app from closing by phone clear app's

Tags: android, flutter, performance, dart, flutter-dependencies

So I've made my applications and its core feature is work in the background when app is minimized or closed (done by creating a foreground notification with `flutter_foreground_task` package). It works perfect in most cases, app works even if screen is turned of, but I found that if I clear my phone's RAM using Xiaomi phone clearing tool it stops and kills my app's process too. Is there any way to prevent this?

My code is complex, but I can provide some code parts if it's needed fore better understanding of my app. The foreground notification created step by step from the package example.

Comment: Be aware of: https://dontkillmyapp.com/